# class database close connection

Tags: php, class

I have two php classes, the following:

```
class Database 
class User
```

in class Database there is the __constructor to create Db connection:

```
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->dbConnect();
```

in class User i have included the class Database in this way:

```
require_once('database.php');
```

and the User constructor instantiate the db connection

```
//constructor
public function __construct() {
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->dbConnect();
    $this->conn = $db;
}
```

How can I close the db connection correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can either make destruct() method or you can make any custom method to close the db connection and call that method with that "$this->conn"

example :

```
mysqli_close($this->conn);

function __destruct(){
  mysqli_close($this->conn);
}
```

First refer your database class file it might having connection close method.